# XSLT - How to determine an element is last in context

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<data>
    <item group="A">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="B">BBB</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
</data>
<data>
    <item group="C">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="D">BBB</item>
    <item>EEE</item>
</data>
```

I would like a value of "true" returned when the the last "item" element in the second "data" element. In this example, I have only 2 "data" elements, but in reality, the number of data elements were vary.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@group]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">    
    <xsl:attribute name="lastdata">
      <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could post the exact output you expect to get from your example?

Comment: So you don't want it for last item in the first `data` element? When there are more than two, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

You create the `lastdata` attribute but you don't have any element created.

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="lastdata">
      <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

By the way, your XML example doesn't contain the root element and your XSL example actually doesn't create any element at all.

Answer (score 0):

the XPath "following-sibling::item" asks for "item" tags on the same level. To test if the "data" parent is the last we use the same XPath selector.

My Input XML-File:

```
<root>
  <data>
    <item group="A">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="B">BBB</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
  </data>
  <data>
    <item group="C">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="D">BBB</item>
    <item>EEE</item>
  </data>
</root>
```

I use the Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item[not(following-sibling::item)][parent::data[not(following-sibling::*)]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="lastdata">
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And get the Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <data>
    <item group="A">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="B">BBB</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
  </data>
  <data>
    <item group="C">AAA</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item group="D">BBB</item>
    <item lastdata="true">EEE</item>
  </data>
</root>
```